# Why auto ID it increase at 10 then it not increase more in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

Please helps me and this my sub code in vb.net
Why auto ID it increase at 10 then it not increase more in vb.net

```
 Sub autoID(ByVal firstID As String, ByVal tbl As String, ByVal tblID As String, ByVal txt As TextBox)
    connect()
    sql = "SELECT MAX(RIGHT([" & tblID & "],4)) AS id FROM [" & tbl & "]"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    reader.Read()
    If Not reader.HasRows Or IsDBNull(reader.Item("id")) Then
        txt.Text = firstID & "0001"
    Else
        Dim newID As Integer = reader.Item("id")
        newID += 1
        txt.Text = firstID & newID.ToString("0000")
    End If
    conn.Close()
    txt.ReadOnly = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete and unclear. you are incrementing it only once. Please try to rephrase your question.

Comment: If you have a real auto incrementing ID (e.g. Identity(1,1) for Sql Server) you don´t have to do anything in code. Also be aware that your code is not multi-user capable.

Comment: Your question is not very clear about how the id values are being stored but you should be careful with using the MAX function on strings as they are treated alphabetically and therefore '9' is 'higher' than '10'. Which sounds like the sort of problem you are experiencing.

Comment: It is not an "auto id" if you are managing it in code.  Using MAX as the basis for an ID scheme is bound to fail eventually,  Let the DB do its job and issue the ID

Comment: It is impossible to say "why auto ID increase at 10 and then it not increase more" looking at only to the vb.net subroutine showed in the OP.. you should explain the logical flow that should have do increase your "tblID" field and then show the code about this flow..